# Slide down keyframe animation doesnt work when closing menu item

Tags: css, css-animations

Submenu css:

```
.app-menu__list .app-menu__list {
  border-left: var(--border-active);
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 2.875rem;

  animation-duration: .8s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  animation-name: slideDownMenu;
}
```

Toggle behavior css:

```
.app-menu__list-item .app-menu__list {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.app-menu__list-item--open .app-menu__list {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible; 
}
```

Keyframe animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideDownMenu {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-12%);
        opacity: 0;
    }       
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
        opacity: 1;
    }   
}
@keyframes slideDownMenu {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-12%);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The animation is working fine when clicking on a menu item. The child menu slides open perfectly. However, on closing a menu item there is no animation and the child menu just gets hidden away instantly.

I think this has to do with the fact that `display: none` immediately gets set on close but i'm not sure..

Answer (score 0):

Yes the issue is with the `display:none` property you need `height:0` to `auto` to achieve that purpose like below

```
.app-menu__list-item .app-menu__list {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.app-menu__list-item--open .app-menu__list {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible; 
}
```

use `width` along `height` for more accurate result .